# Is it possible to select columns based on variable labels?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

With a very wide dataset, is it possible to use variable labels to select columns?

```
library(expss)
data(mtcars)
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      mpg = "Miles/(US) gallon",
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      disp = "Displacement (cu.in.)",
                      hp = "Gross horsepower",
                      drat = "Rear axle ratio",
                      wt = "Weight (1000 lbs)",
                      qsec = "1/4 mile time",
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-engine" = 0,
                             "Straight engine" = 1),
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      gear = "Number of forward gears",
                      carb = "Number of carburetors"
)
mtcars %>% 
  select(contains("Miles"))
```

This doesn't work because it looks in the column names. Can it look at labels instead?

Edit: I should add, aside from the obvious of converting the labels to column names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could get the `attributes` 'label', check for the 'Miles'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mtcars %>% 
   select(where(~ str_detect(attributes(.)$label, 'Miles')))
```

-output

```
#                      mpg
#Mazda RX4           21.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
#Datsun 710          22.8
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7
#Valiant             18.1
#Duster 360          14.3
#Merc 240D           24.4
#Merc 230            22.8
#Merc 280            19.2
#Merc 280C           17.8
#Merc 450SE          16.4
# ..
```

---

Or using `base R` (with `R 4.1.0`), loop over the columns with `lapply`, extract the `labels` attribute, use `grep` to return the elements that matches the `pattern` 'Miles', get the `names` and use that in `select` of `subset`

```
mtcars |>  
    lapply(\(x) attributes(x)$label) |> 
    grep(pattern = 'Miles', value = TRUE) |> 
    names() |>
    {\(x) subset(mtcars, select = x)}()
```

-output

```
#                      mpg
#Mazda RX4           21.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
#Datsun 710          22.8
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7
#Valiant             18.1
#Duster 360          14.3
#Merc 240D           24.4
#Merc 230            22.8
#Merc 280            19.2
# ...
```

Comment: Strange, running your above example yields an error. R 4.1.3, dplyr 1.0.9, stringr 1.4.0:
Error in `select()`:
! `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @KlausPeter I was using `dplyr` `1.0.8` with `R 4.2.0`

Comment: @KlausPeter probably, you used the original data `data(mtcars)` instead of the labelled one in the OP's question check the `apply_labels` part