# Using where to select columns based on variable labels

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code from [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664607/15488435) yields the following error:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mtcars %>% 
  select(where(~ str_detect(attributes(.)$label, 'Miles')))
#> Error: `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
```

How can I get this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `dplyr` 1.0.7

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mtcars %>% 
   select(where(~ str_detect(attributes(.)$label, 'Miles')))
                     mpg
Mazda RX4           21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
Datsun 710          22.8
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7
Valiant             18.1
Duster 360          14.3
Merc 240D           24.4
Merc 230           
...
```

---

Note that in the linked question, the OP did create labels with `apply_labels`.  If we are applying this on a dataset without having no attribute `labels`, it result in error

```
>data(mtcars)
> mtcars %>% 
+   select(where(~ str_detect(attributes(.)$label, 'Miles')))
Error: `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

---

If we want to avoid the error, can wrap it in `any_vars` after extracting the names

```
> nm1 <- names(which(unlist(lapply(mtcars, function(x) 
       str_detect(attributes(x)$label, "Miles")))))
> mtcars %>% 
   select(any_of(nm1))
data frame with 0 columns and 32 rows
```

Comment: I'm using 1.0.7.

Comment: @nicholas have you created the labels with `apply_labels` as in the question